# Cann't Scroll posts in group Facebook

Tags: facebook, web-crawler

I crawling data in group facebook, I using selenium and I emulator bot same real person, I crawling in m.facebook.com, it's very easy to analyze. But I got a problem, some group when I scroll only get max 20 post, example: https://m.facebook.com/groups/3260883254031956, and some gorup when I scoll can scroll limited, example: https://m.facebook.com/groups/hanoihome.

I tring change USER_AGENT to "Mozilla/5.0 (Android 4.4; Mobile; rv:41.0) Gecko/41.0 Firefox/41.0", "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; HTC One M9 Build/MRA58K) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.98 Mobile Safari/537.36", but html response in that USER_AGENT is hard than [www.facebook.com](http://www.facebook.com).

I want crawling in [www.facebook.com](http://www.facebook.com), but this page is very hard to parser and get data, You can help me why some group in m.facebook.com only scroll 20 post and how to fix it! Thank you! You need login to see this case, because I need crawling data from private group so I must login.

Comment: Just so you know. Facebook doesn't allow you to scrape their website so don't be surprised when you get banned.

Comment: I talk about using browser same simple user, no crawling issue yet. I emulator my bot same person, so I test using facebook as simple user.